# Powershell Get Installed Version of Software F-Secure

Tags: windows, powershell

The Script should find out if F-Secure is installed and when installed get the Version:
This works for me:

```
$fsecure= (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion | findstr "F-Secure")
$fver = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like '*F-Secure*'} | % {$_.DisplayVersion})
```

When the Client has more then one Version of F-Secure installed I need to handle all values. How can I do that?

Example Output:

> F-Secure Client Security Premium - AntiVirus & AntiSpy-Schutz            14.55.111
>   F-Secure Client Security Premium - Ger?testeuerung                       2.00.102
>   F-Secure Client Security Premium - Internet-Schutzschild                 10.10.110
>   F-Secure Client Security Premium - Software-Updater                      2.21.1646
>   F-Secure Client Security Premium 13.11                                   13.11

In this case $fver should be 13.11. But because all values start with the same name I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Build a RegEx for `F-Secure Client Security Premium <versionnumber> <EOL>` and filter the output against the regex?

Comment: I will try this. Thanks. But what is <EOL> at the end?

Comment: End Of Line, you can suggest that the line ends at a current position in regex with `$`.